# Returning the number of items in a list

Tags: java

I have a method called `public int getSize()` and it is suppose to return the number of items in the list.  the instance variable is `private Listable[] items;`   I thought it would just be something like this:

```
int size = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
size++;
}

return size;
```

But when I run it through these tests I get this nullpointerexception on the `for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++){` line

I don't think it likes `items.length` for some reason. I'm not getting any errors in Java. How should I do this?

i already tried return items.length;

that didnt work either.

Comment: the variable items is null. By the way, you don't need the loop, just return items.length;

Comment: i already tried return items.length;  it did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you forgot to initialize the variable. Try something like:

```
items = new Listable[10];
```

For your getSize() method, you just need to return `items.length`

Comment: yeah you nailed it.  i forgot to initialize the variable.  it works now, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/java-how-to-get-size-of-list/

I saw this article when I was browsing the web it contains the code that implements the list.size() method.

```
List<String> ls=new ArrayList<String>();

ls.add("one");
ls.add("Three");
ls.add("two");
ls.add("four");

int sizeOfList=ls.size();

System.out.println("Size of List :"+sizeOfList);
```

Answer (score 2):

As MeBigFatGuy has commented (+1) your items variable is null.  In fact, his comment entirely answers your question...  Here's an implementation that should do what you want:

```
public int getSize() {
  return items == null ? 0 : items.length;
}
```